# More info on TF2 free account limitations

Tags: team-fortress-2

Valve published a [FAQ](http://www.teamfortress.com/freetoplay/faq.php) page to describe the differences between free and premium accounts.

It is written that free account has **Limited blueprints**, but what does it mean? Which are the items that a free account cannot craft using recipes?

And also, free account can drop only **Standard** items, but what are the **Rare** and **Cosmetic** items that they can't drop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure **cosmetic** refers to [Hats](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Hats) and [Misc](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Misc) items.

To my knowledge items are only referred to as **rare** on the new crafting screen ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDyZX.jpg)).
At first it looks like they describe the same as cosmetic, but I think they mean the [5 set hats](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Sets#Polycount_sets) which are not only cosmetic, but actually have an influence on gameplay.

Following by that, I would assume free accounts miss the [blueprints for headgear](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Blueprints#Headgear).

There's also the special category in the crafting screen ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnndy.jpg)) which currently contains blueprints which require special ingredients that could only be acquired during the Halloween event.

Comment: By that definition of "cosmetic items" missing, shouldn't for example the Ol' Snaggletooth be included? Without it, you won't be able to have the No-Headshot modifier, which isn't just cosmetic, it's gamechanging

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a free player myself, so I'll mark this answer CW.

- It appears non-premium players do not receive hat or crate drops.
- It appears non-premium players cannot craft hats, or other cosmetic items.
- Cosmetic hats would be hats and tools. (?)
- Rare items would be strange weapons and unusual hats.